# The 'returns' tag value in documentation doesn't seem to appear?

Tags: c#, tags, documentation

I was just documenting a file I wrote, when I discovered that the `<returns> STUFF </returns>` isn't appearing, when I hover over my method although the `<summary> STUFF </summary>` does appear!

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Requests the first service of type T.</summary>
/// <returns>
/// The requested service if found, null otherwise.</returns>
public static T Request<T>() where T : class, IService, new()
{
    return Request<T>(0);
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
var inventory = Services.Request<InventoryManager>();
```

*Hovering mouse over Request* - *sees only the summary*

This is the first time I use official documentation via the `///` and tags, so sorry if this was a stupid question, as I'm sure I'm missing a very simple option/setting. I looked for the problem but didn't get accurate results - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, VS.Net's hover tooltip doesn't show the `return` documentation. (Try it with any of the built-in .Net classes.)

Comment: What can be done about it then? - Write it like: `<summary> This does this and that. <br> Returns: a cool value! </summary>`? (the `<br>` isn't creating a new line btw, not sure how else I'd do that...)

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Remember the summary is exactly that, so you want to keep it brief but include all the relevant information. (Something that the .Net runtime's own documentation frequently fails at.)

Comment: @vexe: [`<para>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x640hcd2.aspx), more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx